# Hit OutOfMemoryError when load large blob column from mysql

Tags: mysql, blob, out-of-memory

One of my table contains one blob column, and sometimes the size of the column value would be more than 500M, which is larger than the defalut max heap size, e.g. -XMX is setting as 512M in my Application Server.

In my code, I have set the fetch size of `PreparedSTatement` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to utilize the Mysql Stream support.

Also, I add `"useServerPrepStmts=true"` into the database url. With these settings, I can insert record with large column (>500M) successfully, but when I trying to get the record, I always hit OutOfMemoryError when calling `ResultSet.next()`.

Note: execute query can pass, checked with the heap size change, execute seems don't load any real record data.

```
ResultRet rs = Prestatement.execute(...).   
rs.next();
```

The mysql driver I'm using is 5.1.17.

Below is the exception stack. It looks like the driver tries to load the whole column value into memory, which cause OutOfMemoryError here.

```
13-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer.ensureCapacity(Buffer.java:156) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer.writeBytesNoNull(Buffer.java:514) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readRemainingMultiPackets(MysqlIO.java:3219) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3077) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2979) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3520) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:935) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1433) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic.nextRecord(RowDataDynamic.java:416) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic.next(RowDataDynamic.java:395) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:7165) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:169) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:169) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ResultSetWrapper.invoke(ResultSetWrapper.java:66) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at $Proxy68.next(Unknown Source) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.db.DbDataStore.openStream(DbDataStore.java:542) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.db.DbInputStream.openStream(DbInputStream.java:68) 
2013-09-18 13:18:00,169 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.db.DbInputStream.read(DbInputStream.java:110)
```

Comment: try to set xmx higher and see it the error occurs

Comment: I think it could work. But increse the JVM heap size is not solution to me, because we suppose user could insert even big object (say 1GB) if he/she requires to, because we announce the APi support stream object, with no restriction of the stream size. From our testing, Oracle could support this. I think Mysql also could support this, but may need some specific configuration or coding.